# mod_rewrite only on GET

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, post

It's a longshot, but I'm hoping to find a simple workaround for a bizarre bug that only manifests when the query string is omitted/inferred by the application.

Before I dig deep into a thousand lines of minified 3rd party javascript, I'd like to find out if I can just auto apply the querystring using mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteRule    ^index\.php$  index.php?module=Home&action=index
```

Now, this would work fine except sometimes all the data will be POSTed so I need a `RewriteCond` so the rule will only fire on `GET` requests, and not `POST` requests.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this condition...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
```

...to not match `POST` requests.

Comment: I knew it had to be something like that. I dug through the docs and came up empty-handed. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 19):

I'd recommend being explicit and only firing the RewriteRule when the request method is GET, rather than whenever it's not POST as there are numerous other methods. So your rewrite condition could look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  =GET

RewriteRule    ^index\.php$  index.php?module=Home&action=index
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> - **Server-Variables:** These are variables of the form `%{ NAME_OF_VARIABLE }` where `NAME_OF_VARIABLE` can be a string taken from the following list:
>
>   ...
>
> **connection & request:**
>     ...
>   REQUEST_METHOD

So, yeah. Use `RewriteCond` with that server variable.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for GET requests...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET [NC]
```