# LARAVEL API - Routes not giving expected behavior. Mistake known and showed here, and I need to know the cause

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, validation

I'm currently working in the Laravel 6.X version. And, I'm making a REST API for the time being. Now, the project is at bare minimum with nothing changed except for a simple Test model, Test Controller and API routes as show in below codes.

```
<?php

// File: TestController

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use http\Env\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Test;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    function getAllMessages(Request $request)
    {
        return Test::all();
    }

    function getMessage(Request $request, int $id)
    {
        //Get the message
        $test = Test::find($id);

        // Check if message exists or not, and send response
        if (is_null($test)) {
            return response()->json([
                "error" => "Test message not found"
            ], 404);
        }

        return $test;
    }

    function addMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            "message" => "required|string|min:5",
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $validator->errors()->all();
        }

        $test = new Test();
        $test->message = $request->input("message");

        // save test
        $test->save();

        return response()->json($test, 201);


    }

    function updateMessage(Request $request, int $id)
    {
        $test = Test::find($id);

        if(is_null($test))
            return response()->json(["message" => "Test not found"],404);

        $test->message = $request->input("message");

        $test->save();

        return $test;
    }

    function deleteMessage(Request $request, int $id)
    {
        $test = Test::find($id);

        if(is_null($test))
            return response()->json(["message" => "Test not found"],404);

        Test::destroy($id);

        return response()->json(["message" => "Test deleted successfully"],200);


    }

    function deleteAllMessages(Request $request)
    {
        Test::truncate();

        return \response()->json(["message" => "All messages deleted successfully."],200);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

// File: create_tests_table

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTestsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('message')->default('');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tests');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

// File: routes/api.php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Test;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/v0.0.1/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Test Message Routes
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Simple route to test the API capabilities of the Laravel application
 */
Route::get('/v0.0.1/tests', "TestController@getAllMessages");
Route::get('/v0.0.1/tests/{id}', "TestController@getMessage");
Route::post('/v0.0.1/tests', "TestController@addMessage");
Route::put('/v0.0.1/tests/{id}', "TestController@updateMessage");
Route::delete('/v0.0.1/tests/{id}', "TestController@deleteMessage");
Route::delete('/v0.0.1/tests', "TestController@deleteAllMessages");
```

The Test Model is simply an empty class at the moment.

Now, with above code, you guys can quickly pick up the pace with me. I have tested all the routes with Postman and all are working fine. **Except, there is one unwanted behavior in the API route.**

The one I'm talking about is the POST route. Normally, it works fine when you send a POST request to the *http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v0.0.1/tests*. But, when the POST request is sent to *http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v0.0.1/tests/*, the server is returning a result of the GET request, not processing the POST request.

The header includes *Content-Type:application/json* and *Accept:application/json*. I want the POST request to send the object back when it is created, but the POST request never returns the object. It instead sends all the object similar to my GET request to */v0.0.1/tests* route.

**I understand that the error is by me in adding an extra forward-slash to the POST route.** But, why is a simple '/' at the end resulting Laravel to give a different response.

My concern is that expected behavior though met is giving unexpected result right now. Please help me fix the issue.

**UPDATE 1::**

HERE IS HOW I AM SENDING THE REQUST IN POSTMAN.
1. Proper request

```
POST request to http://127.0.0.1/api/v0.0.1/tests
headers: Content-Type:application/json and Accept:application/json
body: {"message":"hello" }
returns: 200 OK 
{"id": 1,"message": "hello","created_at":"2019-01-01 12:25AM","updated_at":"2019-01-01 12:25AM"}
```

2. Request Troubling me

```
    POST request to http://127.0.0.1/api/v0.0.1/tests/
    headers: Content-Type:application/json and Accept:application/json
    body: {"message":"hello" }
    returns: 200 OK 
    []
```

Note: The response is empty array as there aren't any entries for now. But, if you put some, it would show all exisiting entries like the GET request for all entries.

**UPDATE-2:: Here is my .htaccess file from the *public_html* folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**END-UPDATE**

Thank you for giving me your time. I hope you have a wonderful day.

Comment: Usually this happens when you have a rule to strip out trailing slashes in an `.htaccess` or something like that. Such rules result in a redirect which would change the request from POST to GET

Comment: Can you show us how you are sending the request?

Comment: I have added the information on how I am sending the request as well.

Comment: It's like @apokryfos said, it might be a redirection that's stripping the trailing slash at the end of your request.

Comment: I've added the .htaccess file as well. Maybe that should help. I do not know much of the apache config files so I did not edit it when I rolled out from wordpress to Laravel application.

Comment: Yes the .htacecss is indeed redirecting the request, which explains your GET request. You simply have to send the POST without the trailing slash at the end.

Comment: Please write it in the answers section. I would be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222815/mod-rewrite-only-on-get might help as well